# Passing Type to class with generics in runtime scala

Tags: scala, class, reflection

I have the class:

```
class MyClass[T <: AnyRef : Manifest](implicit classTagT: ClassTag[T]) {
 ...
 }
```

I have the variable:

```
val t: Type = typeOf[...]
```

How I can do that:

```
val c = new MyClass[t]
```

Comment: Sorry, scala.reflect.api.Type

Comment: You can edit it rather than apologising

Comment: I think you mean `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type`. Do you really need to get the `Type` runtime variable? If you can do `typeOf[A]` you can also simply do `new MyClass[A]`. Is there some layer in between that prevents you from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

First, `Manifest` extends `ClassTag`, so the declaration looks suspicious. You likely want to remove one or the other (better `Manifest`, if possible).

Second, you can't do exactly what you want. But you can construct `ClassTag` or `Manifest` from `Type` and pass it manually (as @stefanobaghino points out, this shouldn't be necessary if you get `t` from `typeOf[...]`). Approximately (untested):

```
val t: Type = ...
val clazz = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.runtimeClass(t)
ManifestFactory.classType(clazz) match {
  case m: Manifest[a] =>
    val c = new MyClass(m, m)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
New problem :)
Error:(138, 32) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[Nothing]
 required: Manifest[T]
Note: Nothing <: T, but trait Manifest is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: T`. (SLS 3.2.10)
        new CaseClassBuilder()(m)
                               ^

Comment: I fixed it
val c = new MyClass(m.asInstanceOf[Manifest[cls.type]])
Is it normal?

Comment: That compiles, and probably works because generic parameters don't influence anything at run-time (but can lead to different implicits being chosen at compile-time), but doesn't make sense: `cls.type` is the type whose only instance is the object `cls`, not the class represented by `cls`. What is correct would depend on the context you use this code in.

Comment: Yes, this is not entirely correct, because of this, sometimes an error occurs. Do not tell me how to write more right?